# Ansible get hostname as defined in inventory

Tags: ansible, hostname, ansible-inventory

In my inventory I define hosts like this:

```
 [server1]
 141.151.176.223
```

I am looking for a variable which keeps the `server1` name, as I am using it to define server hostname.

`inventory_hostname` is set to `141.151.176.223`
`ansible_hostname` as well as `inventory_hostname_short` is set to `148`.

To workaround this problem I am setting my own variable like this:

```
 [server1]
 141.151.176.223 hostname=server1
```

but I am not satisfied with this approach.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Explanation**

If the inventory file was defined this way:

```
[server1_group]
server1 ansible_host=141.151.176.223
```

Then you can access:

- `server1` with the `inventory_hostname` fact;
- `141.151.176.223` with the `ansible_host` fact;
- `server1_group` with `group_names|first` (`group_names` fact contains a list of all groups server belongs to, `first` selects the first element from that list).

Regardless of the above, `ansible_hostname` fact contains the host name as defined on the host itself (the value is set during facts gathering).

---

**Solution**

You should use a standard `ansible_host` declaration to point to the target's IP address and set the inventory hostname to however you want to refer to the server in Ansible playbooks.

In particular you can skip groups definition altogether and define just:

```
server1 ansible_host=141.151.176.223
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I wasn't aware that I was using Ansible wrong. I've fixed my inventory :)

Comment: if you could provide exact syntax how to access what would be really grateful

Answer (score 3):

The `[server1]` declaration is the name of a [group](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#hosts-and-groups), not a host (even if you only assign a single host to that group).

As ansible allows a host to be placed in multiple groups, you can only get the names as an array: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts

So I think the workaround that you found is the way to go, unless you can use real host names instead of IP addresses (using DNS or just static hosts file).